# No insertar duplicados en tabla SQLITE3 - Python 3.6

Tags: python, base-de-datos, sqlite3

Bien tengo una tabla para cada 'Diccionario' de palabras, cada tabla tiene una única columna llamada 'palabra' y permito al usuario cargar un fichero .csv con las palabras que desea introducir en la base de datos. Todo esto lo tengo implementado y funciona. Lo que quiero hacer es que no se repitan las palabras en una tabla. Para ello había pensado añadir la restricción UNIQUE al crear la tabla para la columna 'palabra'. El problema viene cuando se repite la primera palabra, entonces salta una excepción y las que vienen detrás de esa no se insertan. No puedo copiar todo el código por temas de privacidad, espero que esto sirva:

```
        #Carga el fichero en un dataframe para manejarlo internamente
        df_words = pd.read_csv(file, sep=';', header=None)

        #Crea una tabla temporal
        df_words.to_sql('temp_table', db_con, if_exists='append', index=False)

        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO "+name+" (WORD) SELECT * FROM temp_table")

        cursor.execute("DROP TABLE temp_table")

        db_con.commit()
```

Bien yo hago esto, cargo el fichero en un dataframe con la librería 'Pandas', y mediante una función de la librería paso los datos a una tabla temporal y de esa tabla ya los paso a mi tabla. Finalmente borro la tabla temporal. Como decía el problema es que al repetirse una palabra salta una excepción y deja de insertar el resto de palabras. El funcionamiento que quiero es que si se repite alguna palabra continue con la siguiente. Esta es la linea que genera la excepción:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO "+name+" (WORD) SELECT * FROM temp_table")
```

**EDITADA**

Bien pues probando, he pensado que si en lugar de hacer el INSERT INTO en una sola linea, puedo hacer una consulta a la tabla temporal:

```
cursor_temp.execute("SELECT * FROM temp_table")
```

Y entonces recorrer ese cursor intentando insertar la nueva palabra en la tabla original. Tal que así:

```
for i in cursor_temp:
            par = [name_table, word,]
            try:  # Intentamos hacer esto.
                cursor.execute("INSERT INTO ? (WORD) VALUES(?)", par)
            except:  # Si da error, informamos de ello.
                print("La palabra ha dado error")
```

El problema es que esta linea:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO ? (WORD) VALUES(?)", par)
```

Me arroja el siguiente error y no lo entiendo porque lo he hecho muchas veces así y funciona perfectamente:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO ? (WORD) VALUES(?)", par)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si ya tienes el unique usa: `INSERT OR IGNORE ...`

Answer (score 0):

### **Brecha de seguridad:**

Jamás deberías hacer esto:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO "+name+" (WORD) SELECT * FROM temp_table")
```

En su lugar utiliza:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO ? (WORD) SELECT * FROM temp_table", (name,))
```

El por qué (tienes una guía para evitar la injeccion de código) aquí: http://bobby-tables.com/

### **Respecto a tu problema:**

Creo que lo mejor que podrías hacer es un simple try/except: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp

```
try:  # Intentamos hacer esto.
  cursor.execute("INSERT INTO ? (WORD) SELECT * FROM temp_table", (name,))
except:  # Si da error, informamos de ello.
  print("La palabra {0} ha dado error".format(name))
else:  # Si no ha dado error...  
  # haces lo que quieras con esos datos, meterla al dataframe o algo.
finally:  
  # Cuando ya hemos acabado, desconectamos la base de datos o lo que quieras.
  db_con.close()
```

Al menos te servirá para identificar qué palabras dan error y por qué se repiten. A partir de ahí podrás implementar una mejora para que no de error o chequeos sencillos como "si la palabra no está en el dataframe...".

Comment: Buenas Saelyth, sigo teniendo el problema que comento en mi Pregunta, una vez que salta la primera excepción con la primera palabra repetida ya no continua introduciendo las demás.

Comment: La variable `par` es un tuple en tu código? Aunque sea de un solo valor, debes asegurarte de que sea un tuple, como hago en mi ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres seguir manteniendo esa estructura de usar una tabla temporal lo más sencillo es modificar la sentencia `INSERT` para que no inserte las palabras que ya existen.

Así que en lugar de usar:

```py
query = "INSERT INTO " + name + " (WORD) SELECT * FROM temp_table"
cursor.execute(query)
```

podrías usar

```py
query = '''
INSERT INTO {name} (WORD)
    SELECT palabra
    FROM temp_table 
    WHERE palabra NOT IN (SELECT WORD FROM mytable)
'''.format(name=name)
cursor.execute(query)
```

[Adjunto fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/errjrzMK495WLJcr3MCY27/0).

Esta forma de hacer la query no es muy eficiente, pero creo que es la más "sencilla" de ser entendida. En caso de problemas reales de rendimiento se puede complicar un poco a cambio de perder legibilidad.

Una forma un poco más avanzada soportada por muchas bases de datos es usar la clausula [UPSERT](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html) o su equivalente para ese base de datos.

No puedo probarlo ahora pero en sqlite debería ser algo como esto:

```sql
INSERT INTO " + name + " (WORD)
SELECT * FROM temp_table
ON CONFLICT(WORD) DO NOTHING;
```

Pero el upsert sólo suele estar disponible en las últimas versiones (al menos en sqlite y postgresql).

Pero comentan en otras [respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/238876/16970) y en la propia [documentación de psycopg](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#the-problem-with-the-query-parameters):

> Nunca, nunca, NUNCA uses la concatenación de strings de Python (+) o la interpolación de parámetros (%) para pasar variables a una query SQL

Especialmente, si esos parámetros pueden venir del usuario de algún modo. Es muy fácil que produzca un problema de seguridad conocido como [SQL Injection](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL) que está bien descrito (con sus posibles soluciones) en la página de de [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Generalmente se entiende por pasar párametros a una query los que substituirían el `VALUES (%s, %s)`, `WHERE id = %s`, ... y se soluciona simplemente pasando una tupla como segundo valor a [cursor.execute](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.execute), aunque hay otras opciones como [named parameters](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries).

```py
myvalue = 'example'
query = "INSERT INTO my table (WORD) VALUES (%s);"
cursor.execute(query, (myvalue,))
# generará algo como esto en sqlite
# INSERT INTO my table (WORD) VALUES ("example");

myvalue = 'example'
id = 5
query = "UPDATE mytable (WORD) VALUES (%s) WHERE id = %s;"
cursor.execute(query, (myvalue, id))
# generará algo como esto en sqlite
# INSERT INTO my table (WORD) VALUES ("example") WHERE id = 5;
```

En tu caso no se trata de pasar parámetros si no de construír una query dinámica. Para ello psycopg provee de utilidades en el paquete [psycopg2.sql](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html#module-psycopg2.sql).

```py
from psycopg2.sql import SQL, Identifier

tablename= 'mytable'
myvalue = 'example'
id = 5

query_tmpl = "UPDATE {} (WORD) VALUES (%s) WHERE id = %s;"
query = SQL(query_tmpl.format(Identifier(tablename))
cursor.execute(query, (myvalue, id))
```

De modo que la respuesta definitiva a tu pregunta sería algo como:

```py
from psycopg2.sql import SQL, Identifier

query = SQL('''
INSERT INTO {tablename} (WORD)
    SELECT palabra
    FROM temp_table 
    WHERE palabra NOT IN (SELECT WORD FROM {tablename})
'''.format(tablename=Identifier(name)))

cursor.execute(query)
```

Comment: Me gustaría probar la forma que me dices Francisco pero no termino de entender: INSERT INTO mytable (WORD)
    SELECT palabra
    FROM temp_table 
    WHERE palabra NOT IN (SELECT WORD FROM mytable) No se como sustituir los parametros

Comment: Acabo de editar la query, ten en cuenta como dicen en otro comentario que sólo deberías hacerlo de este modo si "name" es un parámetro tuyo, y no un valor que viene del usuario, si no estás sujeto a SQL Injection

Comment: Y como podría hacerlo de otra manera para evitar el SQL Injection??

Comment: La pregunta es `name` realmente es una variable? De donde sale. Es un valor que viene del usuario en algún momento, o está controlada siempre por el programador.

Comment: Esa variable viene del usuario, pero viene de un control de Lista desplegable (checkbutton), es decir el usuario no tiene libertad para insertar lo que quiera. Únicamente puede elegir entre una serie de opciones.

Comment: He ampliado bastante mi respuesta explicando el problema del SQL Injection y las soluciones. No he probado el código por lo que puede haber algún typo, pero si soluciona tu problema estaría bien que aceptaras la respuesta.